# EF6 Foreign Key Issue

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Here are my models

```
public class Driver
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Vehicle Vehicle  { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }

    public int VehicleGroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual VehicleGroup Vehicles { get; set; }
}
```

I'm getting the following error on updating database:

**Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'AppName.Models.Vehicle' and 'AppName.Models.Driver'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.**

I wish to solve the issue using data annotations. I've tried putting foreign key attribute over Driver Navigation property in vehicle model. But no success. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to explicitly set the end of the association like this :

```
public class Vehicle
{  
    [Key, ForeignKey("Driver")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }

    public int VehicleGroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual VehicleGroup Vehicles { get; set; }
}
```

I think your model is inccorect because a driver can use many vehicles in real life ;)

Comment: Can i place [ForeignKey("Vehicle")] over VehicleId attribute in Driver Model?

Comment: What is the association between Driver and Vehcile :
- One Driver can drive multiple Vehicles
- One Driver can drive only one Vehicule

Comment: One to one. Are there any changes between EF5 and EF6 in setting Foreign Key attributes?

Comment: If it's one-to-on you need to remove VehicleId on Driver. After use [Key, ForeignKey("Driver")] opn Vehicle class and all will work fine.